# How to use ApfloatMath.round()?

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal, apfloat

In this snippet I expected "2" as the result?

```
Apfloat f = new Apfloat("1.5", 50);
f = ApfloatMath.round(f, 15, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(f.toString());
```

Or should [ApfloatMath.round()](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/) be used differently?

Comment: You expect 2 but what you get in `System.out.println(f.toString());`

Comment: I'm getting "1.5" as result.

Comment: Try to set the second parameter to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard of apfloat but one google query showed me:

```
round(Apfloat x, long precision, RoundingMode roundingMode)
```

So apparently you are rounding with a precision of 15, why do you expect 1.5 to magically become 2?

In other words: set precision to 0 or 1 (depends on the implementation)

Comment: f = ApfloatMath.round(f, 1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); thanks this works :-)